# Node-red on Pi: Unable to send/receive to Arduino Leonardo via USB serial

Tags: usb, serial, arduino

I'm connecting a Arduino Leonardo to Pi4 (P3b+ has the same issue). I wish to send and receive data from it in node-red (using serial nodes from the standard palette).

I can see that Arduino is sending the data to /dev/ttyACM0 (using "screen /dev/ttyACM0").  Sometimes the serial data shows up in /dev/ttyAMA0.

Console login has been disabled.

In any event, node-red shows that the port is connected but no data comes through.

---

21 Sep 10:09:41 - [info] Started flows
21 Sep 10:09:41 - [info] serial port /dev/ttyACM0 opened at 57600 baud 8N1
21 Sep 10:09:41 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/

---

I should add that as Leonardo could do HID. The same port could be used to send mouse instructions. I don't think this would be a factor.

Comment: the arduino is set to `57600 baud 8N1` as well?

Comment: I verified that "screen" could talk to the port. Maybe "screen" adapts to the baud rate. I don't know.  Just in case. I have also set the baud rate to 9600 and the same issue.

Comment: I inserted one USB to TTL adapter, and $ ls /dev/usb* returns hiddev0 hiddev1. $ ls /dev/ttyA* returns /dev/ttyAMA0.  My python program import serial and serial port = '/dev/serial0'.  I vaguely remember reading that AMA0 is replaced by serial0. It is so confusing! :(

Comment: Your question is unclear. On the Pi3/4 `/dev/ttyAMA0` is normally connected to Bluetooth and will NOT be used for serial, although it can be assigned to UART pins on the GPIO. It will NEVER be used for USB.